# Y-coordinate of UITabBar subview

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a custom subclass of a `UIViewController` (without a nib), which I'm pushing onto a `UINavigationController` stack.  Somewhere during the initialization of my `UIViewController` subclass (`loadView`? `viewDidLoad`? `init`?) I want to add a `UITabBar` subview to the bottom of the view.  The problem is figuring out the Y-coordinate.  As far as I can tell, the view gets resized somewhere after `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, and `init` so I can't get the resized height in order to calculate the Y-coordinate of the UITabBar.

What is the proper way to figure out the height of the containing view such that I can anchor the UITabBar at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set your `UITabBar` to the bottom of the view, and then *tell it to stay there* if the bounds of the superview changes.

This isn't too tricky. For example, in `viewDidLoad` alloc/init the tab-bar as normal, and position it as follows:

```
tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.height-tabBar.frame.size.height, 0,
                          tabBar.frame.size.height, tabBar.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:tabBar];
```

...which will add the bar to the bottom of the view.

So far so good: your problem is when the superview changes height the tabbar doesn't stay locked to the bottom. To fix this, we set an autoresizing mask:

```
tabBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskTopMargin;
```

...which will effectively lock the bar to the bottom of the superview.

Comment: Many thanks.  I've done a lot of work with the iPhone, but never fully grasped the entire layout thing with these UIViews.  I'm still used to HTML layouts.  I found another solution by subclassing a UIView, adding the UITabBar to that, and positioning with layoutSubviews.  Still good to know the autoresizing mask.  Cheers.